# Why the collapse of electron in nucleus considered unstable?

Tags: electromagnetism, atomic-physics, subatomic

In Rutherford's Atomic structure proposal, when electron loses energy while orbiting the nucleus and collapses, why do we consider this situation as unstable when there is saturation of electric field of nucleus and electron upon complete contact, hence it has to be more stable than before.

Comment: It would no longer have the structure of an atom and chemistry (based more or less on electron “shells”) could not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is because if the electrons were to be in contact with the nucleus, we would revert back to Thomson's plum pudding model, wherein negatively charged electrons were said to be embedded in a positively charged entity. But this model was in fact the one unable to explain Rutherford's gold foil experiment.